# HTML5 Drag Issue: Offset between the cursor and dragged text

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-draggable

I am trying to implement drag/drop in my html page which seems to work fine.
   The only issue I see is that when I start drag of the draggable text, there is a vertical offset between the cursor and the  text that is being dragged (depicted in the pic below).
   Is there any way I can compensate this offset?

[image: Original Text]

[image: When drag starts]

PS: This is a part of a larger project which is why I am unable to paste the code here.